# ruby on rails update_attribute is not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying update information of a current_user by a following method:

```
current_user.update_attribute(:country, "")
```

but it's not updating anything.
when I was doing the same in console everything was fine.
Please help me with this issue?

Comment: try `current_user.update!(country: "")`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it IS updating the record in the `users` table, but note that it won't change the attribute automatically in the copy of the record in memory.

Try this...

```
current_user.update_attribute(:country, '')
current_user.reload
```